# Fragment Visibility

Tags: android, android-fragments, visibility

A lot of threads ask the question how to run code or get the visibility of the fragment.
But I would like to know "why" the Fragments: onResume() and onStart() are 'not' visible to the user, although the documents state it should be visible to the user.

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

> onStart() makes the fragment **visible to the user** (based on its containing activity being started).
>   onResume() makes the fragment interacting with the user (based on its containing activity being resumed).

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume%28%29)
and onStart() for that matter, clearly describe:

> Called when the fragment is **visible to the user** and actively running. This is generally tied to Activity.onResume of the containing Activity's lifecycle.

While I clearly see no fragment, till after onResume has completed. Soo the question remains: 'why' is the fragment only 'visible' after onResume. and not from onStart as per doc?
Oh and the expand on this: I use no ViewPager.. Just a simple Activity-Fragment model.

Hope anyone has some intel on this...

**[UPDATE*]** I have added a sample project with one activity and one fragment showing the issue. For anyone to try ;-)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/08noqvmq7sjwppb/fragmentUserVisibilityTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you have a long running operation in your `onStart()` which happens in the main thread. In this case you won't see anything until this operation ends. Which happens by the time `onResume` is called. Consider using `AsyncTask` for long operations.

`onStart()` gets called when a fragment is *about to be shown*, `onResume()` is called when a fragment *is about to be interactible*. That's the same as for an Activity.

`onStart()` and `onResume()` would have been of no use, if they had been called *after* a fragment becomes visible/interactible.

Comment: Thanks for your input; Although very likely this would be the case. I have no long running operations on the onStart() or any other methods.

Do you think it could have something to do with?:
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

Comment: Normally, they do replace().commit() in activity's onCreate if savedState == null (otherwise the fragment is already there). Also, you can try setRetainInstance(true) in your fragment's onCreate so your fragment stays between configuration changes. Have no idea if this helps or not.

Comment: I will try this also. For now I have uploaded a sample project, for anyone to try out. Which shows what I saw. (see original question)

Comment: Sorry to inform you, it did not have any effect.